# How do I calculate the confidence interval from the standard error?

Tags: confidence-interval, survival, kaplan-meier

When using the Kaplan Meier estimator function in MedCalc, medcalc gives me the  the survival proportions at each observed timepoint as well as the standard error for that proportion, so I can for example say "At 2 years the overall survival is 87% with a standard error of 7%., p = 0.06"

Is there an easy way to calculate the confidence interval for that survival proportion from that info?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the $87\%$ and $7\%$ would be an estimated mean and standard deviation of the [sampling distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution) for the reported statistic. In general these parameters can be used to compute a confidence interval, assuming a known parametric form for the distribution function.

In your case the normal approximation is not fully appropriate, as $0.87\pm{2}\times{0.07}$ gives an interval $[0.73,1.01]$ whose upper bound exceeds $100\%$. A reasonable alternative could be to assume a [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). In this case the 95% confidence interval corresponding to your numbers would be $[74.1\%,96.2\%]$.

I am not sure exactly how the calculation might incorporate the reported $p$ value? With the Beta interpretation above, the "[effective sample size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Mean_and_sample_size)" would be $\hat{n}\approx{23}$, if that helps.

---

Note that the [MedCalc manual](https://www.medcalc.org/manual/kaplan-meier.php) says there is an option to 
"Include 95% CI in graph", which is probably the easiest solution in your situation. This will presumably produce a result that is consistent with the software's underlying statistical model, as well.